# Ffmpeg broken first segment

Tags: google-chrome, video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player

I have big problem with saving h264 stream to mp4 with ffmpeg.

I'm using different options without any results. When I'm stopping ffmpeg during create of first segment, the output .mp4 files won't play in Windows Media Player or Opera, but it is playing in VLC and Chrome. Second segment is playable on every browsers and players. Here is my rule:

```
ffmpeg -re -fflags discardcorrupt -fflags +genpts -i http://192.168.11.227:86/main -strict -2 -r 24 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -f segment -segment_time 30 -reset_timestamps 1 -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -segment_format mp4 /mnt/sda1/segment_%d_$(date+%d_%m_%Y"_"%H_%M_%S).mp4
```

Comment: "When I'm stopping ffmpeg during create of first segment, the output .mp4 files won't play" So don't stop it then ...

Comment: So how can I Grab strem to segments for example 1h log and what if I Will want to stop są Ing stream  before  1h because stream sometime is shorter than 1h.